# AS3 Merge multidimensional arrays

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, multidimensional-array

Say I wanted these two arrays

```
array1 = [
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];

array2 = [
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]];
```

to become this

```
array3 = [
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], 
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]];
```

is there a way one can do this?
It might not be the best solution to what I am trying to do, but without that good of experience with as3 it's the best thing I can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    var array1:Array = [
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];

    var array2:Array = [
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]];     

    var array3Ref:Array = [
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], 
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]];

    var size:int = Math.max(array1.length, array2.length);
    var array3:Array = [];
    for(var i:int=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array3[i] = array1[i].concat(array2[i]);
    }

    trace(array3.toString() == array3Ref.toString());
```

output:

```
true
```

Be aware, it doesn't handle the case, when `array1` and `array2` has different length.